# Is it possible to inline pass input as a parameter

Tags: c++

I think my question is better illustrated with code, is it possible to do something like this:
C#
`SetSomeMember(Console.ReadLine())`
or
Java
`SetSomeMember(sc.nextLine())`

in C++? Something like:
`SetSomeMember(std::cin)` 
?

Comment: Yes, `getline` uses that method for example : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to quickly get a value of type `T` from `std::cin` you can create a simple helper function:

```
template <typename T>
T get_from_cin()
{
    T result;
    std::cin >> result;
    return result;
}
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
struct foo
{
    void setSomeMember(int);
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.setSomeMember(get_from_cin<int>());
}
```

---

If you instead want to get an entire line as an `std::string`, look into [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Usage:

```
std::string temp;
std::getline(std::cin, temp);

whatever.setSomeMember(temp);
```